# Adding New Dictionary

Tags: macos, dictionary

I am following the instructions at the bottom of [this article](http://jsomers.net/blog/dictionary) article to add the Webster's dictionary to my dictionary.app list. It does not seem to be working (the new dictionary does not show up in the dictionary.app preferences pane.

I think the problem might be because I am on Mavericks but the dictunifier app is from 2011. Does anyone know of a workable way? The dictionary tar.bz file contains files with the extension .dict.dz, .idx, and .ifo.

Comment: I am also running Mavericks and was able to add the dictionary.